# How to use cordova plugins in with typescript

Tags: javascript, cordova, typescript, plugins

I am doing an app for Android using Cordova and Typescript. I can't manage to make cordova plugins work with it, although it was working when I was doing it just using Javascript. For now I am trying to convert my old Javascript code to Typescript and organize it with modules, but I am not comfortable with it.

For example with this [cordova-plugin-sms](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms/), I still get this error : `www/js/manageSMS.ts(23,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SMS'`, both in my IDE (PHPStorm) and in the console when I try to run the app. The plugin is well installed, and I managed to make it work before, using Javascript. There're no types for this plugin, but I can still use it right ?

I have two ts files, one index.ts (main) and one manageSMS.ts (module).

Here's the index.ts :

```
import {SMSManager} from "./manageSMS";

export class CordovaApp {
    constructor() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
        let blockSentences = document.querySelector('#blockSentences');
    }

    onDeviceReady() {
        console.log("The device is ready");
        let sms = new SMSManager();

    }
}

let instance = new CordovaApp();
```

Here's my manageSMS.ts :

```
export class SMSManager {

constructor() {
    let filter = {
        box : 'inbox', 
        maxCount : 20, 
    };
}

getAllSMS(filter) {
    if (SMS) SMS.listSMS(filter, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }, function(err){
        console.log('error list sms: ' + err);
    });
}

}
```

My config.ts :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowJs": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "plugins",
    "platforms",
    "typings",
    ".idea"
  ]
}
```

Let me know if you need any more file.